# why did not generate the app_localization.dart file

Tags: flutter, dart, intl

when I am using this command to generate `app_localization.dart` file in dart project:

```
~/fvm/versions/3.3.9/bin/flutter pub run intl_utils:generate
```

the `app_localization.dart` did not generate and also no error ouput. what should I do to make it genreate file success? this is the `pubspec.yaml`:

```
name: untitled
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.5 <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: 0.17.0
  intl_utils: ^2.8.2


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
flutter_intl:
  enabled: true
```

I also tried to generate using this command:

```
$ ~/fvm/versions/3.3.9/bin/flutter pub run intl_utils:generate --output-dir=lib/localization                                                         ‹ruby-2.7.2›
INFO: No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_en, assuming 'en' based on the file name.
(base)
```

did not generate the `localization` folder.

Comment: Assuming you have added flutter l10n.yaml in the root folder. Have you tried with : flutter command gen-l10n in the terminal

Comment: command is "flutter gen-l10n"

Comment: I have tried what you said and found the file generate in `.dart-tool/flutter-gen/gen-l10n` folder. @Niladri Raychaudhuri

Comment: the file in root folder named l10n.yaml should have the line "arb-dir: lib/l10n". This is the path where you have the .arb files having the localised Strings. Once you run the  command flutter gen-l10n, it should update the folder with app_localizations.dart file. For more details follow: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization